# pandas: populate df column with values matching index and column in another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing a problem that I am uncapable of finding a way around it.

I find very difficult too to explain what I am trying to do so hopefully a small example would help

I have `df1` as such:

```
Id   product_1   product_2  
Date
1    0.1855672   0.8855672
2    0.1356667   0.0356667 
3    1.1336686   1.7336686  
4    0.9566671   0.6566671
```

and I have  `df2` as such:

```
                            product_1    Month
Date                                          
2018-03-30                         11.0      3
2018-04-30                         18.0      4
2019-01-29                         14.0      1
2019-02-28                         22.0      2
```

and what I am trying to achieve is this in `df2`:

```
                            product_1    Month   seasonal_index  
Date                                          
2018-03-30                         11.0       3        1.1336686 
2018-04-30                         18.0       4        0.9566671
2019-01-29                         14.0       1        0.1855672
2019-02-28                         22.0       2        0.1356667
```

So what I try is to match the product name in `df2` with the corresponding column in `d1` and then get the value of for each index value that matches the month number in `df2`
I have tried doing things like:

```
for i in df1:
    df2['seasonal_index'] = df1.loc[df1.iloc[:,i] == df2['Month']]
```

but with no success. Hopefully someone could have a clue on how to unblock the situation

Comment: This is basic merging, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) question and answer.

Comment: it might @Erfan you are right but I dont find a way to do it, because wouldn't be mergin on ```month```, but there is no month column in ```df1```. I'll attempt anyways, thanks.

Comment: Try something like this `df2['season_index'] = df2['Month'].map(df1.set_index('Date')['product_1'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are my friend, this produces exactly the output you specified.

```
import pandas as pd

# replicate df1
data1 = [[0.1855672, 0.8855672],
         [0.1356667, 0.0356667],
         [1.1336686, 1.7336686],
         [0.9566671, 0.6566671]]
index1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data1,
                  index= index1,
                  columns=['product_1', 'product_2'])
df.columns.name = 'Id'
df.index.name = 'Date'

# replicate df2
data2 = [[11.0, 3],
         [18.0, 4],
         [14.0, 1],
         [22.0, 2]]
index2 = [pd.Timestamp('2018-03-30'),
          pd.Timestamp('2018-04-30'),
          pd.Timestamp('2019-01-29'),
          pd.Timestamp('2019-02-28')]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, index=index2,
                   columns=['product_1', 'Month'])
df2.index.name = 'Date'

# Merge your data
df3 = pd.merge(left=df2, right=df[['product_1']],
               left_on='Month',
               right_index=True,
               how='outer',
               suffixes=('', '_df2'))
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'product_1_df2': 'seasonal_index'})
print(df3)
```

If you are interested in learning *why* this works, take a look at this link explaining the pandas.merge function. Notice specifically that for your dataframes, the key for df2 is one of its columns (so we use the left_on parameter in pd.merge) and the key for df is its index (so we use the right_index parameter in pd.merge).

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html